# Is this implementation of a graph effectively linear in the number of edges?

Tags: c++, data-structures, space-complexity, directed-graph

I have a class which resembles an adjacency matrix representation of a weighted, directed graph. Let's suppose the graph has `n` vertices. Here is how it works:

- At first, allocate n<sup>2</sup> slots to hold integers (stored in a variable named `graph`), in the form of `n` arrays each having `n` integers.
- Assign weights to the edges, where `graph[i][j]` represents the weight of the edge going from vertex `i` to vertex `j`.
- Deallocate any unused slots in the graph

Sample code:

```
class DiGraph {
    public:
        Graph() {}
        Graph(size_t n) {
            graph.resize(n);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                graph[i] = new int[n]{-1};
            }
        }
        void addEdge(int from, int to, int weight) {
            graph[from][to] = weight;
        }
        int& getEdge(int from, int to) {
            return *(graph[from] + to);
        }
        void finalizeGraph() {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if (graph[i][j] == -1) {
                        delete &graph[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<int*> graph;
};
```

Now I want to implement an algorithm that is only supposed to work on the existing edges of the graph. In other words, the algorithm is not supposed to create new edges other than the ones that already exist in the input graph. I want to efficiently use memory and at the same time achieve the O(1) access to any edge between two vertices.

Is the space complexity of the above implementation of the graph **effectively** linear in the number of edges?

Comment: For starters you can't "deallocate any unused slots in the graph" and still be able to use the array notation `graph[i][j]` to access the edges.  Adjacency matrix does not have "unused slots" it has slots, that indicate that there is no edge.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the class that holds the graph has the required overloads to accomplish this.

Comment: In that case I doubt the access to the edges is O(1).

Comment: Why? Suppose that for each vertex you have an array that stores the weights of all outgoing edges. You fill in the edges you want and then deallocate any unused array entries in the middle of the array. Since you have the starting addresses of the arrays you can jump to anywhere in the array provided you have the vertex number you want to jump to.

Comment: You cannot deallocate distinct array elements. Array is a contiguous memory region, you can't make "holes" in it.

Comment: I can call `delete` on individual array elements rather than `delete[]`ing the entire array.

Comment: No, you can't. Perhaps you can delete some object that this array element is pointing to, in case it is an array of pointers, but not the element itself. Since you are not showing your implementation it is hard to reason further.

Comment: @WaisKamal "I can call delete on individual array elements rather than delete[]"---> Even if you could do this, then by definition your algorithm would be O(n^2), because in the worst case you would delete `O(n^2)` items.

Comment: @Ari but that's a one time cost so I am not concerned with it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I will add some code.

Comment: @WaisKamal When you mention "call delete on individual array elements", this means you waist at least one unit of time for each entry. This means that you have to interact with the OS `O(n^2)` times.

Comment: I think your definition of what a "slot" is is the key question (at least initially).  If a "slot" is a single edge weight vs. a "slot" is an entire list of edge weights for a specific node.

Comment: @franji1 a slot is a single edge weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not, unless you can prove that the way you allocate and deallocate the edges is independent from `n`, which based on your description is unlikely.

Remember that `Big O` notation considers the worst case of your algorithm. Since you first allocate `n^2` slots and then remove the non-existing edges, your algorithm runtime in the worst case is `O(n^2)`, not `O(n)`. In other words as `n` grows, your algorithm runtime also grows with `O(n^2)` since you have to allocate and deallocate edges that don't exists. This is true, unless you can prove that the way you allocate and deallocate the edges is independent from `n`.

In order to get to a liner runtime in terms of edges, you need a different data structure that in which the amount of work for edges is `O(m)`, where m is the number of edges.

However, you can argue that if such a graph is given, i.e. the non-existing edges are removed, then the access time for each edge can be `O(1)`, assuming your data structure supports it.

Comment: I don't really care that much for the time it takes to allocate and deallocate the arrays, as that is trivial compared to the time it would take to access the edges in an adjacency list representation. I don't want to use a hashmap since it needs more memory. Ignoring the time taken for allocation/deallocation, is this effectively linear in space? I mean, will the OS be able to efficiently utilize the unused "holes" in the arrays?

Comment: You are either talking about the mathematical definition of `Big O`, in which case the answer is no, as I mentioned above, or you want to create your own definition with some approximations, which is fine and there is no problem with that. Yes, if you assume allocation and deallocation time is negligible (which I don't think it is), then you can say my algorithm is linear. And yes it is true that the OS might be able to use those holes later on. But as n grows the allocation and deallocation can be very significant. Heap access time is not something that you can ignore.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=335zQkHDWRY

Comment: > I don't really care that much for the time it takes to allocate and deallocate the arrays.     Yeah, sorry, but you're not allowed to not care. The whole point of `O()` notation is that when `n` is large enough, allocation becomes the limiting factor

Comment: @Ari sorry if I was not clear, but I am actually more concerned about the space complexity than the time complexity. I will add the relevant tag to the question.

Comment: @Ari thanks for the link. I am not sure though how the map and set implementation deals with outgoing edges from a particular vertex that have the same weight.

Comment: @WaisKamal: I think you would get a better answer if you post exactly what you are trying to do. 

Maybe you can consider using an unordered map that maps a pair of nodes to a weight. This way the access time is still `O(1)` on average, and your memory footprint is `O(m)`.

Note that even if you are concerned about memory, `Big O` is still holds for the worst case. If you can tolerate allocating a gigantic amount of memory in the beginning and then gradually deallocate it, then it might work, but you may not be able to do that.

Comment: @Ari I thought about this: if the memory limit is so tight, I will allocate the first part of the array, remove the unused slots, then move on with allocating the second part. Regarding the answer, I think it answers the question on the first line: "*No it is not, unless you can prove that the way you allocate and deallocate the edges is independent from n*". Anyways, I would have to run some benchmarks to decide which one (hashmap vs array) is more efficient for my use case. Thank you!